# How to determine whether two variables have the same sign in R

Tags: r

For example, I have two variables a and b. They are both numbers. I would like to check whether they have the same sign (both positive or both negative) or they have different signs. If one of them is 0 (they can't be both 0), then I considered them as different signed.
I know I can write

```
if (a*b<=0) ...
```

but I don't think it's a good way because a and b are both large numbers and R gives a warning:

```
Warning message:
In b[i - 1, 4] * b[i, 4] :NAs produced by integer overflow
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sign` might be useful here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good idea would be to use the `sign()` function in R which returns `1` or `-1` if a number is positive or not and `0` if the number is 0.  You can chain these together like this:

`sign(x)==sign(y)`

edit: Thanks for the correction about returning 1/-1/0 rather than TRUE or FALSE, I completely missed that when I played around with it this morning.

Comment: `sign` in R returns -1, 0, or 1, thus `sign(-1) & sign(1)` is equal to `TRUE`. So the correct answer using `sign`, would be `sign(x) == sign(y)`.

Comment: @alko989: this should be the answer, or else amblina's post should be corrected to reflect this.

Comment: @jbaums: I commented (and downvoted) to say that the post needs corrections. If it is corrected I would also consider up-voting the *correct* answer.

Comment: @alko989 Thanks for the correction, you are completely correct in regards to `&` vs `==` and I have editted my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
f <- function(a,b) {ifelse(a == 0 | b == 0,as.logical("FALSE"),!xor(sign(a)+1,sign(b)+1))}
```

Function `f` returns logical `TRUE` for same signs and `FALSE` for different signs or if one the variables is equal to `0`

Comment: No need for "as.logical("FALSE")" -- just plain `FALSE` will suffice.

Comment: Also no need in `ifelse`, as there are no vectors here